# Ошибка при добавлении в список методом append

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x, python-3.7, append

Есть список из десятка url. Начинаю в цикле for их перебирать, парсить html и формировать словарь из данных с каждого линка. Потом хочу передать получившийся словарь в созданный ранее список, но происходит нечто неожиданное. Вместо ожидаемого списка словарей с данными по каждому линку, получаю в нем 10 одинаковых словарей, созданных на основе данных с последнего линка.

```
article = {}
articles = []

    for i in links:
        article['link'] = i
        r = requests.get(i, headers = headers)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
        title = soup.find_all('h2')[0].get_text()
        article['title'] = title
        article['date_pub'] = soup.find_all('time', class_='b-date')[0].get('datetime')    
        articles.append(article)
```

Распечатываю содержание переменной article внутри цикла. Все работает корректно, каждый раз скрипт создает новый словарь. Но в момент добавления к списку происходит нечто непонятное. Вместо добавление, происходит его полная замена. Например, при втором прохождении цикла for два раза один и тот-же словарь со второго линка... Ну и далее. Что это и как оно исправить?

Comment: Это ожидаемо: один раз вы создали словарь `article = {}`, а после везде ссылку на него используете. Нужно создавать словарь на каждой итерации списка. И, для наглядности, лучше используйте `article = dict()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это ожидаемо: один раз вы создали словарь `article = {}`, а после везде ссылку на него используете.

Нужно создавать словарь на каждой итерации списка. И, для наглядности, лучше используйте `article = dict()`:

```
articles = []

    for i in links:
        article = dict()
        article['link'] = i
        r = requests.get(i, headers = headers)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
        title = soup.find_all('h2')[0].get_text()
        article['title'] = title
        article['date_pub'] = soup.find_all('time', class_='b-date')[0].get('datetime')    
        articles.append(article)
```

Или можно сразу же создавать словарь:

```
    for i in links:
        r = requests.get(i, headers = headers)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
        title = soup.find_all('h2')[0].get_text()

        article = {
            'link': i,
            'title': title,
            'date_pub': soup.find_all('time', class_='b-date')[0].get('datetime'),
        }
        articles.append(article)
```

---

**PS.**

Советую, типизировать данные, например через [NamedTuple](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.NamedTuple):

```
from typing import NamedTuple, List

class Article(NamedTuple):
    link: str
    title: str
    date_pub: str

...

articles: List[Article] = []

    for i in links:
        r = requests.get(i, headers = headers)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
        title = soup.find_all('h2')[0].get_text()
        date_pub = soup.find_all('time', class_='b-date')[0].get('datetime')

        article = Article(i, title, date_pub)
        articles.append(article)
```

Сможете после к полям `article` обращаться, плюс будет подсказка от `IDE`:

```
print(articles[0].date_pub)
```

Еще значения полей можно вернуть как словарь:

```
print(articles[0]._asdict())
```

Comment: спасибо, осознал. Больше никогда так делать не буду. Сейчас прокручу так, а потом добавлю типизацию.